# Error 500 Could not create PG connection when registering kafka connect PG connectors with multiple brokers

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I try using multiple brokers kafka when single distributed mode doesn't satisfied me. But i get another problem when registering kafka source Postgresql connectors. It always sent me error 500 when registered it. Here's my kafka connect distributed config:

```
bootstrap.servers=
group.id=connect-cluster
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
#offset.storage.partitions=25
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=3
#status.storage.partitions=5
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
...
plugin.path=/home/admin/kafka/connectors
```

and this is how i define one of the connectors:

```
    {
"name":"...",
    "config":{
        "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "plugin.name":"wal2json",
...
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":...
        "database.history.kafka.topic":"history_analytics_menu",
        "table.whitelist":"...",
        "transforms":"unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
        "decimal.handling.mode":"double",
        "time.precision.mode":"connect",
    "transforms":"dropPrefix",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"...",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"..."
        }
    }
```

Is there something i missing?

UPDATE:

This is what i got from kafka-connect:

```
[2020-03-21 12:25:29,390] ERROR Uncaught exception in REST call to /connectors (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper:61)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Could not create PG connection
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to XXX refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    ... 21 more
```

and from connectors curl:

```
{"error_code":500,"message":"Could not create PG connection"}
```

Comment: So you have three brokers, all running locally? And how many Kafka Connect workers? What's the *actual* error that you get from Kafka Connect?

Comment: I will put in my details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified a host/port for Postgres that is not reachable from where Kafka Connect is running

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:15432 refused. 
Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Comment: i see... got problem that i realised that postgres host not live. I will check it about it

Comment: yeah my fault... the postgres connection is dead... i have fixed it... many thanks

Comment: Good stuff - feel free to mark the question correct if it is, to help others find the answer in the future :)